# A problem while rendering wineglass in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have been trying to make a wineglass with filling using curves. In Eevee everything displays correctly, but I cannot say the same thing about Cycles. How can I fix this strange effect? I have tried turning curves into meshes, tried using Subdivision Surface, did not help. Any help appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, please pack your image and share your file so that we can see: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Just how you asked: [link](https://pasteall.org/blend/677666341a43413c8036250171fe17a8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem of normals, you need to flip the normals in the *Screw* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for Russian :)

Comment: well I guessed what it was  ;)